# Use URL data to fill form in Django with Class Based Views

Tags: python, html, django, django-class-based-views

I have 2 Models: **Projects** and **Members**, each one with a form. I was able to add to the URL the number of the project (id) this:

```
class PageCreate(CreateView):
    model = Page
    form_class = PageForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('members:create')
 
    
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('members:create', args=[self.object.id])
```

When I finish of filling the **Project form**, it redirects the page to the **Member form**.

What I want to do is to extract the ID of the Project from the URL and use it in the **Member form**. I cannot think any other solution.

Currently I have a Selection list to select the **Project** in the **Member form** but I want the Project loaded as soon as is created.

I am using the CreateView in the models for both Projects and Members. This is the view for **MemberCreate**

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class MemberCreate(CreateView):
    model = Member
    form_class = MemberForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pages:pages')
```

Only attempt I had to visualize the ID in the HTML was using

```
{{ request.get }}
```

To somehow get the value from the GET but I could not do it.

Url Parameters

```
import imp
from django.urls import path
from .views import PageListView, PageDetailView, PageCreate, PageUpdate, PageDelete, MemberCreate, MemberDelete, MemberUpdate

pages_patterns = ([
    path('', PageListView.as_view(), name='pages'),
    path('<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', PageDetailView.as_view(), name='page'),
    path('create/', PageCreate.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('update/<int:pk>', PageUpdate.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>', PageDelete.as_view(), name='delete'),
], 'pages')

members_patterns = ([
    path('create/<int:pk>', MemberCreate.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('update/<int:pk>', MemberUpdate.as_view(), name='update'),
    path('delete/<int:pk>', MemberDelete.as_view(), name='delete'),
], 'members')
```

Comment: Can you add your urls.py? The value is not in `request.get` if you're using path parameters. Try using `self.kwargs` in the view and pass it to context by using `get_context_data`

Comment: I added the URLs, thank you for you reply, do you have a code block example?

Comment: What is the `pk` in `create/<int:pk>` for `MemberCreate`. Is it the pk of the Project?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that it would help me to load the project id into the URL and the use it from there to fill the Member form with the ID of the project.

Comment: You can do it, the `pk` is in `self.kwargs` of `MemberCreate` view (`self.kwargs['pk']`). See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context for an explanation on how to add extra context in the template. The same function can be used in the `CreateView`

Answer (score 0):

Stuff parsed from the URL ends up in the view's `self.kwargs`.  From

```
  return reverse_lazy('members:create', args=[self.object.id])
```

you pass through an URL like

```
path( 'create/<int:project>', MemberCreateView.as_view(), name='create' )
```

and in the view, the id is now `self.kwargs['project']`. (note, an URL can specify multiple named variables separated by slashes, it's not limited to just one). You typically then use

```
project = Project.objects.get( pk = self.kwargs['project'] )
```

Request.GET is something different: it's where the dict encoded as a querystring goes. If your client supplies

```
http://server/app/foo?bar=27&baz=hello
```

then  when you arrive in the view which handles app/foo, request.GET contains

```
{ 'bar':'27', 'baz':'hello' }
```

(actually it's a QueryDict, not a Python dict, which has some subtle diffreernces. Consult the Django documentation. The main difference is that the values attached to keys can be multi-valued, for a querystring like `?bar=27&bar=54&bar=silly`